# How to sum a single column array with another array (going column by column)?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

The code below allows me to add a vector to each row of a given matrix using Numpy:

```
import numpy as np
m = np.array([[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9], [10, 11, 12]])
v = np.array([1, 1, 0])
print("Original vector:")
print(v)
print("Original matrix:")
print(m)
result = np.empty_like(m) 
for i in range(4):
  result[i, :] = m[i, :] + v
print("\nAfter adding the vector v to each row of the matrix m:")
print(result)
```

How do I perform a similar addition operation, but going column by column?
I have tried the following:

```
import numpy as np
array1 = np.array([[5,5,3],[2,2,3]])
print(array1)
addition = np.array([[1],[1]])
print(addition)
for i in range(3):
    array1[:,i] = array1[:,i] + addition
print(array1)
```

However, I get the following broadcasting error:

```
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (2,2) into shape (2)
```

Answer (score 2):

Just match the number of dimensions, numpy will [broadcast](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html) the arrays as needed. In the first example, it should be:

```
result = m + v.reshape((1, -1))
```

In the second example, the addition is already 2D so it will be just:

```
array1 + addition
```

Comment: @EzerK you're right, it is not. The reason to have the reshape it is to make things more explicit, also handling cases when m is a square matrix

Answer (score 0):

You can alternatively, add a dimension via Numpy None syntax and then do the addition:

```
array1 += addition[:,None]
```